# Sigma field of class C and a subset equals to the sigma field of the subset and class C

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a problem understanding the following parts of the proof (Resnick, Path of Probability 19) for: 
$B(Real) \cap(0,1]=B((0,1]) $

2 Questions:

1)
Specifically $\Omega_o \in B_o  $ since $\Omega \cap\Omega_o=\Omega $, and $\Omega \in B$, where B is a Borel Set.

Given C is a class of subsets of $\Omega$, the statement above guarantees that that $\sigma(C) \cap\Omega_o $ is a sigma-field.

QUESTION 1) Why this assures us that it is a sigma field? I think the following:

$\sigma(C) \cap\Omega_o$

Without proving the whole statement $ \sigma(C) \cap\Omega_o=\sigma(C \cap \Omega_o) $  (which the purpose of the whole proof): this is a sigma field because it contains the null set, then if  $A \in C$ and $A \in \Omega \cap \Omega_o=\Omega_o$ this implies $A,A^c \in \sigma(C)$ and because of the restriction for $A \in \Omega_o $, then $A,A^c \in \sigma(C) \cap \Omega_o$. Using a similar argument as the one I just said, the countable unions hold too.

Is this approach right?

2)

Define 
$$G:=(A \subset \Omega: A\cap \Omega_o \in \sigma(C_o)$$
where $C_o :=C \cap  \Omega_o \subset \sigma(C) \cap \Omega_o$.

Then they try to claim that G is a sigma-field since:

i) $\Omega \in G$ since $\Omega \Omega_o=\Omega_o \in \sigma(C_o)$

QUESTION 2) Why does $\Omega \in G$? By the definition of G, I would read it as: "A is a subset of $\Omega$ such that the intersection of A AND $\Omega_o$ is in $\sigma (C_o)$", and that only a part of $\Omega $ is in $G$ and that part is $\Omega_o$. Therefore, I just don't see how G could contain the whole $\Omega$.

I am fairly new, so some obvious things may not look that obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Be very careful: $C$ here is not a subset of $\Omega$, but a set of subsets of $\Omega$.  People usually write it in a different typeface to help distinguish.  So no, $\sigma(C)$ is not $\{\emptyset, C, C^c, \Omega\}$.

Comment: I see. Got that, so $\sigma(C)$ does not equal that as C is not a subset but a class of subsets. Thanks for the clarification. Having said that, I still don't know why  $ \Omega \in G$ instead of $\Omega_o$ .

Comment: @Ahmir Did you figure out this question? if yes, could you look at my question regarding this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819721/showing-a-subset-belongs-to-a-sigma-field  thank you